# Connecting to C# Server from iOS

Tags: c#, ios, tcp, azure

I am trying to make an iOS apps which connects to a C# server (using TCP) programmed similarly to that shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx). On the client (iOS) side, I use CFStreams and the CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost method to connect to my cloud server. I have followed the tutorial found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) precisely for the iOS side. A copy of the main connection program can be found [here](http://numberonekits.com/tcpConnect.m).

Unfortunately, when I run the app, I never get a NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event from the inputStream, even though the server is programmed to send a message to the client immediately after the connection has been made. Can someone help me fix this?

All help is greatly appreciated, and I always accept at least one answer!

Comment: Have you followed this in your IOS app? The string from the client must contain the string "<EOF>" to signal the end of the message.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Maybe its an encoding issue, though (I use NSASCIIStringEncoding on the iOS side)?

Comment: You may want to print out on the server side what was received and what was sent.  And you may want to read this, as he does a good job of giving ideas of how to get more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378001/byteswritten-but-other-device-never-receives-nsstreameventhasbytesavailable-eve

Comment: Server seems to be receiving and sending the messages as it should. Something must be wrong either on the iOS side, or with the TCP packet sent by the server.

Comment: I just figured it out. A rather silly mistake on my part: I was accidentally releasing a string from memory, the one which as supposed to tell me if the connection was successful. As a result, I had though it'd failed, even though it didn't. If you submit your comment above as an answer, I will accept it, since it ultimately helped me find this mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to print out on the server side what was received and what was sent. And you may want to read this, as he does a good job of giving ideas of how to get more info:

[bytesWritten, but other device never receives NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378001/byteswritten-but-other-device-never-receives-nsstreameventhasbytesavailable-eve)